# Как в начальных настройках для модели в AnyLogic задать параметры для Сервиса с очередями?

Tags: моделирование

Необходимо до запуска модели изменить количество сервисов и количество очередей используя элемент управления "бегунок". Как это сделать?


[image: Параметры сервиса с очередями]

[image: Элемент управления "бегунок"]

Comment: Может, я чего-то недопонимаю в вопросе, но вон же кнопки со стрелками вверх/вниз как раз для изменения параметров.

Comment: Все настройки модели вынесены в отдельное окно, параметры передаются в main с помощью "бегунков".

Comment: Вопрос непонятен. Вы спрашиваете как изменить параметры и прикладываете скриншот, на котором прекрасно видно, как их изменить.

Comment: Скорректировал вопрос, так понятно?

Comment: Непонятно. Вопрос выглядит как "у меня есть кнопочный телефон, необходимо позвонить используя дисковый набор. Как это сделать?"

Comment: Представьте что заказчик модели умеет пользоваться только дисковым набором и нужно его каприз выполнить.